# Elementor aiming motion CSS variable

Tags: css, wordpress, variables, animation, elementor

I'm improving my CSS skills but this is too far for me.

You can add motion animations on scrolling to any element in elementor. I'd love to make a media query to use some animation on desktop, and other animations on tablet or phone.

I used the Chrome inspector to know what's going on there, and it said this:

```
<div class="elementor-widget-container elementor-motion-effects-element" style="--translateY:17.075px; transform: translateY(var(--translateY));">
                    <div class="elementor-image">
```

I asume that the CSS variable "--translateY: 17.075px;" is the speed of the animation.

And I tried to make this, on the custom CSS field of the image.

```
:root {     --translate-samba: 116px;}

    
.duna{
    position: relative
}
#guau.samba{
    position: absolute;
   bottom: 10vw;
    width: 100vw;
    transform: translateY (var(--translate-samba)) ;
}
```

But it said: Col 1 rule is empty and right brace expected; and the animation didn't work :(

Any tips? Thanks a lot

Comment: You have a space between translateY and its opening bracket.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but It doesn't work. I'll keep working in other areas of the design/content and I'll try to implement some js code later.